# Best Practice For Mocking Repository Pattern

Tags: moq

I'm starting out with IoC / Mocking and am looking to make sure I'm using 'best practice' for my repositories.

I'm setting up interfaces for my repositories. The concrete implementations will point to SQL, whilst testing will use Moq to generate "fakes". I notice that I'm using Moq's callback feature a *lot*. In [this](http://www.codethinked.com/beginning-mocking-with-moq-3-part-4) article, the author states.

> since Moq provides functionality in both of these areas for most of what you would want to do, there isn’t really too many different points at which you would need these tools. In fact, if you think you need to use “Callback” you should probably look a little harder to see if Moq can do what you want to do automatically.

I've had a look and can't see any other way to implement what I need - namely a 'fake' repository. Can someone please advise if there's something that I'm missing here? Is there any way to achieve this without the callback?

```cs
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        // Arrange
        var mock = ContactRepositoryFake();

        // Act
        mock.Object.AddContact(new Contact() { Name = "bill" });
        mock.Object.AddContact(new Contact() { Name = "jane" });

        // Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(mock.Object.AllContacts.Count() == 2);
    }

    public Mock<IContactRepository> ContactRepositoryFake()
    {
        var _allContacts = new List<Contact>();
        var mock = new Mock<IContactRepository>();
        mock.Setup(x=>x.AddContact(It.IsAny<Contact>()))
            .Callback((Contact c) =>
                {
                    _allContacts.Add(c);
                });
        mock.Setup(x => x.AllContacts).Returns(_allContacts);
        return mock;

    }
}

public interface IContactRepository
{
    void AddContact(Contact contact);
    IEnumerable<Contact> AllContacts { get; }
}

public class Contact
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Thank you very much in advance! Any other advise welcome :-)

Z

Comment: I have to ask, what is the value in mocking database access for testing repositories?  The soul purpose is for accessing the database, 90% of the logic in most of my repositories are Linq queries.  Do these unit tests ever find issues?

Comment: Hi. Look - it's three years later and now I tend to agree with you. I have moved away from writing these types of mocks. They're heavy to write and maintain. It sounds to me like, if you're using LINQ against your repos, they probably support IQueryable? These repo patterns I was using above weren't. They just had methods like "AllContacts" or "RecordsByName". Also, instead of using Mocks like above, I now occasionally implement 'in memory' repos which are just a class that implements the interface and backs it with a dictionary. These are cool as I end up using them in 'real' code.

Comment: Unit testing with a mocked database hasn't ever really made sense to me, I admit I've never tried it.  My approach is to do multiple queries and check that they correlate and are getting expected results. E.g the results are filtered and sorted correctly.  The tests are designed to run against any sample data, tests which are unsuccessful due to incomplete sample data do not fail, instead they return inconclusive.

Many purists would have issues with this as these kind of unit tests could return different results depending on the sample data, however I find them helpful in finding issues.

Comment: If you're connecting your tests to a data source, then isn't this more like an integration test than a unit test? The more tests that I write (and it's probably been thousands this year!) I'm leaning more and more to very concise tests, which often have the data included in the actual test method. If you need to test 10 different data scenarios, then write ten tests... perhaps using a base class to keep 'DRY'....
Of course, integration testing has it's place I suppose. It doesn't have to be taboo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally do not see an issue with the way you are doing this. What I see is that you want to Mock and not Stub you repository. Which means you want it to "record" and return data back during the test. In this case `Callback` is useful and really the only way to do this.

As for the comment if you are dealing with Stubbing more than mocking then `Callback` would be rarely be used. the article imo is a bit to general and doesn't fully see the power of the `Callback`.

Comment: Thanks for that. Good to know that I'm not missing something :-)

Answer (score 3):

You could just setup the following:

```
mock.Setup(x => x.AllContacts).Returns(GetExpectedContactList());
```

and have a helper function which returns a List of Contacts:

```
private static List<Contact> GetExpectedContactList() 
{
....
}
```

And have different Helper methods to return specific data scenarios.

Comment: Hi Ciaran. I think that you've missed the point a bit. The issue is that I need a way for the Mock to record additions to it and then return them. Thanks though :-)

Comment: Oh, ok, I understand your requirement better now.... However, I think you are not really testing the core requirement with the Callback so that's where my confusion stems from.

Your code _allContacts.Add is not your real code so what are you testing? Effectively, it feels to me, you have a test which confirms that List.Add works.

Comment: G'day. Yep - I see your point. After writing a few 'tests' the above way over the past few weeks, I've used the pattern less and less. There are a couple of places where it's proved useful though. 

Thanks for your help :-)